# В чем отличие Socket.SupportsIPv6 и Socket.OSSupportsIPv6?

Tags: c#, .net

`Socket.SupportsIPv6` считается устаревшим и возвращает `false`. Рекомендуемый метод `Socket.OSSupportsIPv6` возвращает `true`. Какому методу верить и почему вообще разница в результате?

Comment: `Какому методу верить` - тому, который `Рекомендуемый метод`

Comment: Для удаления вопроса вы можете нажать кнопочку "удалить" где то под тегами к посту

Comment: @tym32167, нет, не могу удалить. Недоступно это без регистрации.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [исходникам](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,8e2fbfd76b93aba3,references), свойство `OSSupportsIPv6` показывает, возможно ли физически создать сокет со схемой адресации [`AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.sockets.addressfamily.aspx).

Cвойство `SupportsIPv6` отражает значение атрибута `enabled` элемента `system.net/settings/ipv6` из конфига (по умолчанию false). Описание этого элемента можно найти в файле `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config.comments`.